# mapnik installation on Windows giving C++14 standard issue with clang or g++

Tags: windows, installation, clang, c++14, mapnik

I followed the steps mentioed in https://mapnik.org/pages/downloads.html to install mapnik from source.

I have clang version 14. But when I am trying to install mapnik on Windows, it says "C++ compiler does not support C++14 standard (-std=c++14), which is required. Please upgrade your compiler"

$ ./configure CXX=clang++-14 CC=clang-14

scons: Reading SConscript files ...

Welcome to Mapnik...

Configuring build environment...

Configuring on Windows in release mode...

Checking for pkg-config... no

Checking for freetype-config... no

Checking for dlfcn.h support ... no

Checking if compiler (clang++-14) supports -std=c++14 flag... (cached) no

C++ compiler does not support C++14 standard (-std=c++14), which is required. Please upgrade your compiler

The config.log contents are:

```
file D:\projects\qgis\mapnik\SConstruct,line 1266:
Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for pkg-config...
pkg-config --atleast-pkgconfig-version=0.15.0
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for freetype-config...
freetype-config --libs --cflags
'freetype-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for dlfcn.h support ...
.sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp <-
|
|
|#include <dlfcn.h>
|
|int main()
|{
| return 0;
|}
|
|
clang++-14 /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_2.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp /TP -std=c++14 -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 /nologo /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE /Iinclude /ID:\usr\include
'clang++-14' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: no

.sconf_temp\conftest_3.cpp <-
|
|
|int main()
|{
|#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
| return 0;
|#else
| return -1;
|#endif
|}
|
|
clang++-14 /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_3.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_3.cpp /TP -std=c++14 -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 /nologo /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE /Iinclude /ID:\usr\include
'clang++-14' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: Checking if compiler (clang++-14) supports -std=c++14 flag...
scons: Configure: (cached) no
```

If you see config.log, it says "'clang++-14' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Why is it trying to run the command with the version name? If this is not the way, how then should I pass the version to ./configure command?

I tried with g++ (version 6.3.0) as well and got similar issues. My previous clang was version 12 that comes with Visual Studio. When I run just ./configure, the config log says:

```
file D:\projects\qgis\mapnik\SConstruct,line 1266:
Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for pkg-config...
pkg-config --atleast-pkgconfig-version=0.15.0
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for freetype-config...
freetype-config --libs --cflags
'freetype-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for dlfcn.h support ...
.sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp <-
|
|
|#include <dlfcn.h>
|
|int main()
|{
| return 0;
|}
|
|
c++ /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_2.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_2.cpp /TP -std=c++14 -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 /nologo /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE /Iinclude /ID:\usr\include
c++: error: /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_2.obj: No such file or directory
c++: error: /c: No such file or directory
c++: error: /TP: No such file or directory
c++: error: /nologo: No such file or directory
c++: error: /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE: No such file or directory
c++: error: /Iinclude: No such file or directory
c++: error: /ID:\usr\include: Invalid argument
scons: Configure: no

.sconf_temp\conftest_3.cpp <-
|
|
|int main()
|{
|#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
| return 0;
|#else
| return -1;
|#endif
|}
|
|
c++ /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_3.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_3.cpp /TP -std=c++14 -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 /nologo /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE /Iinclude /ID:\usr\include
c++: error: /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_3.obj: No such file or directory
c++: error: /c: No such file or directory
c++: error: /TP: No such file or directory
c++: error: /nologo: No such file or directory
c++: error: /D-DMAPNIK_MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE: No such file or directory
c++: error: /Iinclude: No such file or directory
c++: error: /ID:\usr\include: Invalid argument
scons: Configure: Checking if compiler (c++) supports -std=c++14 flag...
scons: Configure: (cached) no
```

When clang v12 didn't work, I installed LLVM + clang v14. I also tried by exporting variables first like export CXX="clang++-14" and export CC="clang-14". But no luck...
Please help as I am badly stuck in this for the past 2 days...
Thanks

Comment: [MSYS2 Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) seems to work for me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not familiar with MSYS2. Can you elaborate a bit more - so it will install clang if I am not mistaken. Did you run ./configure simply after MSYS2 installation to use that gcc to install mapnik?

Comment: Follow the linked instruction. After installation, install GCC and/or Clang with it, depending on your preference. Then run `./configure`.